# React's unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have read in React docs that keys are not globally unique and that they should be unique per siblings, but why does this code work?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const people = [
   {name: 'John', age: 20},
   {name: 'Danny', age: 35}, 
   {name: 'Rebecca', age: 18}, 
]
const element = (
  <ul>
    {people.map((person, index) => (
      <li key={index}>{person.name}</li>
    ))}

    {people.map((person, index) => (
      <li key={index}>{person.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
element,
document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Aren't all of the resultant `<li>` elements considered siblings, so why I do not get any warning that there are two elements with the same key?

Comment: those kind of keys are useful for keeping aligned the model (i.e. the array), and the generated elements. When a cell of the array changes, the keys help to recognize which is the element generated by that cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way the word "siblings" is used in the docs refers to siblings in a javascript Array, which might not correspond to siblings in in the rendered DOM tree. So it doesn't matter that the `<li/>` nodes will be rendered into the same `<ul/>` parent, React will see them as two different arrays of components.

> ### Keys Must Only Be Unique Among Siblings
>
> Keys used within arrays should
> be unique among their siblings. However they don’t need to be globally
> unique. We can use the same keys when we produce two different arrays.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings